# If $N$ is a normal subgroup of $G$, do $n_p(N)$ and $n_p(G/N)$ divide $n_p(G)$?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, sylow-theory

Here $n_p(H)$ represents the number of Sylow-$p$ subgroups of $H$. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level.

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/), [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559/155238), [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/editing-help#latex).

Answer (score 7):

Hint to get you started: If $N$ is a normal subgroup, then the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $G/N$ are of the form $PN/N$, where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$. Similarly by normality of $N$ the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$ are of the form $P \cap N$, where $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

---

The following is way more than you need for this exercise, but I just want to mention this related fact. If $N \trianglelefteq G$, then

$$n_p(G) = n_p(N) n_p(G/N) n_p(T)$$

where $T = N_{PN}(P \cap N)/ P \cap N$. For a proof, see

> Marshall Hall Jr., On the number of Sylow subgroups in a finite group, Journal of Algebra
>   Volume 7, Issue 3, December 1967, Pages 363–371 [DOI](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0021-8693(67)90076-2)

---

**Later edit:** Here is a proof of the statement above. Let $P$ be a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$.

We have $n_p(G) = [G:N_G(P)]$ and $n_p(G/N) = [G/N:N_G(PN)/N] = [G:N_G(PN)]$ since $PN/N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G/N$. Thus \begin{equation}n_p(G) = n_p(G/N) \cdot [N_G(PN) : N_G(P)] = n_p(G/N) \cdot n_p(N_G(PN)).\tag{1}\end{equation}

Every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N_G(PN)$ is contained in $PN$, so \begin{equation}n_p(N_G(PN)) = n_p(PN) = [PN : N_{PN}(P)].\tag{2}\end{equation}
Note that $PN = N_{PN}(P)N$, which gives \begin{equation}[PN:N_{PN}(P)] = [N_{PN}(P)N:N_{PN}(P)] = [N : N_{PN}(P) \cap N].\tag{3}\end{equation}

Since $N$ is normal, the intersection $P \cap N$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $N$. Furthermore the normalizer of $P$ is contained in the normalizer of $P \cap N$, so $N_{PN}(P) \cap N \leq N_N(P \cap N)$ and \begin{align}[N:N_{PN}(P) \cap N] &= [N:N_{N}(P \cap N)] \cdot [N_N(P \cap N) : N_{PN}(P) \cap N]\\ &= n_p(N) \cdot [N_N(P \cap N) : N_{PN}(P) \cap N].\tag{4}\end{align}

At this point applying $(1)$, $(2)$, $(3)$, and $(4)$ shows that \begin{equation}n_p(G) = n_p(G/N) \cdot n_p(N) \cdot [N_N(P \cap N) : N_{PN}(P) \cap N].\tag{5}\end{equation}

Note that $[A \cap N : B \cap N] = [B(A \cap N) : B]$ for any subgroups $B \leq A$ of $G$. With $A = N_{PN}(P \cap N)$ and $B = N_{PN}(P)$, we have $B(A \cap N) = A$ since $A = P N_N(P \cap N)$. Thus $[A \cap N : B \cap N] = [A : B]$, that is: \begin{align}[N_N(P \cap N) : N_{PN}(P) \cap N] &= [N_{PN}(P \cap N) \cap N : N_{PN}(P) \cap N]\\ &= [N_{PN}(P \cap N) : N_{PN}(P)] \\ &= n_p(N_{PN}(P \cap N)).\end{align}

Plugging this into $(5)$ gives $n_p(G) = n_p(G/N) \cdot n_p(N) \cdot n_p(N_{PN}(P \cap N))$.

Finally $P \cap N$ is a normal $p$-subgroup of $N_{PN}(P \cap N)$, from which it follows that $N_{PN}(P \cap N)$ and $N_{PN}(P \cap N) / P \cap N$ have the same number of Sylow $p$-subgroups. This completes the proof of the result by Hall.

---

**Another remark:** If $H < G$ is not a normal subgroup, then it is not true in general that $n_p(H) \mid n_p(G)$. For example, for $H = S_3$ in $G = A_5$ we have $n_2(H) = 3$ and $n_2(G) = 5$.

However, it is always true that $n_p(H) \leq n_p(G)$ whenever $H \leq G$. See answers to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/694216/if-h-is-a-subgroup-of-g-then-h-has-no-more-sylow-subgroups-than-g).

Comment: Actually, it would be nice to have a proof not involving the Hall reference. His proof is a bit of a turd, surely there are more elegant ways e.g. of showing that $n_p(N)$ divides $n_p(G)$?

Comment: @RomandadeGore: I edited this answer to include a proof of Hall's result. You do not need the whole thing if you just want to prove $n_p(N) \mid n_p(G)$.

Comment: For $n_p(N) \mid n_p(G)$, note that we have $G$ acting transitively on the Sylow $p$-subgroups of $N$. Thus $n_p(N) = [G : N_G(P \cap N)]$, which divides $n_p(G) = [G : N_G(P)]$ since $N_G(P) \leq N_G(P \cap N)$.